# How can I get total sum of each group by using pandas

Tags: python, aggregation

I have a dataframe shaped like below

```
size ind weight weighted_hour
1    A    17       40
1    B    20       41
1    C    19       42
2    A    50       30
2    B    20       10
2    C    13       16
3    A    17       19
3    B    21       23
3    C    23       30
```

and I want to insert some sum of criteria like below

```
size ind     weight weighted_hour Total_WH
1    A       17       40          57
1    B       20       41          61
1    C       19       42          61
1    Total   56       123         179
2    A       50       30          80
2    B       20       10          30
2    C       13       16          29
2    Total   83       56          139
3    A       17       19          36
3    B       21       23          44
3    C       23       30          53
3    Total   61       72          133
```

I prefer to use pandas but if someone can suggest more efficient method
It's good either.
Give me some advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the above dataframe as `df`:

```
df.weight = df.weight.astype(int)
df.weighted_hour = df.weighted_hour.astype(int)
df["Total_WH"] = df["weight"] + df["weighted_hour"]

df1 = df.groupby(['size'], as_index=False).sum().assign(ind='Total')

df = pd.concat([df, df1]).sort_values('size')
```